# How can I access route params in Nestjs middleware

Tags: nestjs, backend, middleware

I'm creating a middleware in nestjs and here is how the structure looks like

```js
export class TestModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(TestMiddleware)
            .forRoutes('/test/:id')
    }
}
```

I'm using fastify Adaptor and I've a question that how can I access the route param in my middleware.
I've tried accessing req.params but it comes empty and can't see any other property having the route param in it.

### UPDATE

Apparently I've found a way to write middleware in fastify which allowed me to access proper fastify request body and response body with params resolved.

For that I've used the package called `fastify-plugin`

In the middleware file you can use it like this

```js
export default fastifyPlugin(
    function (fastify, options, next: VoidFunction) {
        fastify.addHook('onRequest', (req, res, done) => {
           
            done();
        });
        next();
    },
    {
        name: 'auth',
    },
);
```

Comment: I believe this is a limitation. You won't have the parameters parsed at the time the middleware ran even using `express`.

Comment: I never use nestjs with fastify but maybe it require some parser or something similar. Try to print in console raw req object and check it out. Or provide some more details for us...